# How to get all substrings occurring between two characters?

Tags: java, regex, string

If I wanted to pull all substrings between two characters(general) along a String how would I do that?
I also want to keep the first char I match but not the second one.

So, for example, if I wanted ot keep the characters between a `#` char and either the next whitespace OR next of another char (in this case `#` again, but could be anything) and I had a string, say : `"hello i'm #chilling#likeAVillain but like #forreal"`

How would I get, say a Set of `[#chilling, #likeAVillain, #forreal]`

I'm having difficulty because of the either/or end substring case - I want the substring starting with `#` and ending before the first occurence of either another `#` or a whitespace (or the end of the string if neither of those are found)

Put simplest in sudocode:

```
for every String W between [char A, either (char B || char C)) // notice [A,B) - want the 
                                                               //first to be inclusive
   Set.add(W);
```

Comment: `#forreal` is not between `#`. Why is it in your result?

Comment: Why don't you just ask how you get hashtag tokens from tweets?

Comment: hashtags were the best comparison I could make for what I needed - it's not necesarily what I need and Pshemo - sorry I guess the third termination clause would be the end of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex `#\\w+` seems to do what you need. It will find `#` and all alphanumeric characters after it. Since whitespace is not part of `\\w` it will not be included in your match.

```
String s = "hello i'm #chilling#likeAVillain but like #forreal";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output:

```
#chilling
#likeAVillain
#forreal
```

Comment: between this and your pre-edit post I think I got what I need- thanks!

Comment: @gadu If my previous version was the one you needed then you should include escaping mechanism in your regex in case will want to use regex metacharacters like `$`, `^`, `*`, and so on. To make then simple literals you can surround them with `"\\Q"+yourCharacter+"\\E"`. `\Q` and `\E` will make every characters between them literals.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String s1 = "hello i'm #chilling#likeAVillain but like #forreal";
    String[] strArr = s1.split("\\#");
    List<String> strOutputArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    for(String str: strArray){

        if(i>0){
            strOutputArray.add("#" + str.split("\\s+")[0]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(strOutputArray.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Won't it remove "#"s?

Comment: Oops.. added the "#" to it.

Comment: Why do you escape `#`?